# Compile Android Kernel automatically/Tool

Tags: c

i want to compile a kernel for android from my source.

But I want to use a tool or something like that.

So I just click a button and get a flashable zip file...

Is there a tool?

Can I do it with a script?

Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with [this](https://source.android.com/source/building-kernels.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends where you have the kernel from and what your target device will be. Usually you need the right toolchain for your kernel and an approprietary linux environment anyway. Compared to this it's not much to just type the command to compile it in the terminal. If you need further information, xda is always a good source of information, but you have to know more on which phone you are using.
If you have everything together, it is very easy to just quickly set up a custom script which would allow you to compile, pack and flash your kernel in one command. Just add the commands in correct order.